# How to print the Value in hand in game of BlackJack

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the BlackJack game, I am trying to catch the summation of the cards' values in hand and print the same. I want to know about the mistake in my code keeping the same logic that I am working with.

I am returning a Tuple from the init_deal() method of the Deck class and calling the same in the next class i.e Hand. Inside add() function of Hand class, I am trying to sum up the values of the Cards to calculate the total value in hand.

```
import random

suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 
'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')
values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 
'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}

class Card:    
    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit= suit
        self.rank= rank        
    def __str__(self):
        return (f'{self.rank} of {self.suit}')

class Deck:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck=[]
        self.computer=[]
        self.player=[]
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))

    def init_deal(self):
        count=1
        while count<5:
            if count%2==0:
                comp=self.deck.pop()
                self.computer.append(comp)
                count+=1                
            elif count%2!=0:
                playr=self.deck.pop()
                self.player.append(playr)
                count+=1
            else:
                break
        return (self.computer,self.player)

class Hand(Deck):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand=Deck().init_deal()
        self.hand_com=self.hand[0]
        self.hand_playr=self.hand[1]
        self.value_comp = 0 
        self.value_player = 0
        self.val_comp=''
        self.val_player=''        
        self.aces = 0

    def add(self):
        self.val_comp=' '.join(val.split()[0] for val in self.hand_com)
        self.val_player=' '.join(val.split()[0] for val in self.hand_playr)
        self.val_comp_lst=self.val_comp.split()
        self.val_player_lst=self.val_player.split()
        print(self.val_comp_lst)
        print(self.val_player_lst)

        for val in self.val_comp_lst:
            self.value_comp += values[val]
        for val in self.val_player_lst:
            self.value_player += values[val]
        return (self.val_comp,self.val_player)
        print(self.value_comp)
        print(self.value_player)

    def __str__():
        pass #Some logic here

x=Deck()
x.init_deal()
y=Hand(x)
y.add()
```

Lets assume

```
Deck().init_deal()
```

returns

```
(['Two of Hearts','Eight of Diamonds'],['Five of Spades','Six of Diamonds'])
```

So as per my code's expected result:

```
self.hand_com=['Two of Hearts','Eight of Diamonds']
self.hand_playr=['Five of Spades','Six of Diamonds']

val_comp_lst=['Two','Eight']
val_player_lst=['Five','Six']
```

So the ultimate expected result (which actually I am unable to print):

```
self.value_comp = 10
self.value_player = 11
```

But now if I run the code I am getting an error as "AttributeError: 'Card' object has no attribute 'split'"

Please help me to understand the mistake I am doing in this code

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve]. And what debugging have you done?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a dictionary that you use to map the word to the numeric value and then use a list comp and sum to sum up those values:

```
val_comp_lst=['Two','Eight'] 

nums = {'One': 1, 'Two': 2 ...}

sum([nums[x] for x in val_comp_lst])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to add a `value` property to `Card`.

```
class Card:
    _values = {1: 11, 11: 10, 12: 10, 13: 10}
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit= suit
        self.rank= rank        
    def __str__(self):
        return (f'{self.rank} of {self.suit}')

    @property
    def value(self):
        # returns the value from _values, or the rank of the card

        return self._values.get(self.rank, self.rank)
```

Then sum the `value` of the cards in the hand. However be aware that aces are counted as either 11 *or* 1, so you might have to fudge with those numbers afterwards!

---

An aside: I'm confused on your class structure. You write `class Hand(Deck)`, but that implies that a `Hand` *is* a `Deck`, which seems unlikely. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Hi Adam, class Hand(Deck) was written mistakenly as previously I had defined Hand as a function and changed it to another new class later. For aces, I will have another function after this. 
Regarding your solution, could you please guide me, how to use this @property decorator in my code. As I am a beginner in Python, I am unable to catch this properly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: A property is a method that is accessed like an attribute, so in this case `c = Card("Hearts", 2); assert c.value == 2`

Comment: Hi Adam, the execution is being failed at the line:  `self.val_comp=' '.join(val.split()[0] for val in self.hand_com)`  with error message as **"AttributeError: 'Card' object has no attribute 'split' "**

  `  def add(self):
        self.val_comp=' '.join(val.split()[0] for val in self.hand_com)
   `

As per my understanding self.val_comp should be a string which contains value as "Two Eight" which it gets from `self.hand_com=['Two of Hearts','Eight of Diamonds']`, then why the execution is going back to Card class? Is self.hand_com not containing any element?

Comment: @SaikatSantra not sure without looking at the code, but it sounds like a different question than theone asked here. If you'd like to point me at a git repo and a chat service (gitter.im?) I might be able to help further but SO isn't the place to have this sort of detailed code review.